# Hard pain for recover crease

Tags: cricket

I am have much of the time on the RECOVERY crease/s in game of friendly CRICKET

How is best line for pick up of new PITCH ?

I am have much problem in back where speed has very low possible

I am strained, therefore I have no hand for low recovery

thanks,

PRASHANT :)

Comment: I realise English isn't your first language, but is there any chance you can clarify what you mean - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @PRASHANTP it is still very hard to understand what you are trying to say. Hop on Chat and we can see if we can work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read over [TalkCricket](http://www.talkcricket.co.uk/guides/cricket_laws.html)'s description of cricket. And from what I can interpret from your question, you are spending most of your time in recovery. You want to know what the best line for the pickup of a new pitch, and you have pain in your back that prevents you from throwing the ball quickly, and you have no hand to use for low recovery.

From this description, it is very hard to tell what is being asked. Since we cannot read your mind and do now know what you are asking, it is difficult to answer the question.

I suggest you visit some of the cricket strategy websites, such as [PitchVision](http://www.pitchvision.com/playing-swing-bowling), [MyCricketGame](http://www.mycricketgame.com/cricket-strategy.html), and [Dangermouse](http://www.dangermouse.net/cricket/strategy.html). Once you have figured out what you are looking for, Google is your friend. Sports Stack Exchange can also help you, but the members need to know what is being asked first. Look at the links provided and try to determine what the question is, and then edit your question to make it more specific.